# What are the list of instruments in MIDIUtil in python?

Tags: python, documentation, midi

So, I am resigning a python application to edit .mid files, and I am using MIDIUtil to help me with this. I am just asking for a chart containing each instrument in MIDIUtil, and its program change number (zero-based.) I tried checking the documentation, but I can't find such a list.

Answer (score 2):

The MIDI specification itself does not say anything about the meaning of program numbers.

What instruments are available depends on the synthesizer, but nowadays, it's likely that its supports at least the [General MIDI sound set](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/gm-level-1-sound-set).